# Very basic Objective-c Memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties

I am a new in objective-c, I want to know when I return an object like the code below, whether I should autorelease it like this:

```
- (NSArray *)loadCategory
{
    NSArray *temp = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:c1, c2, nil] autorelease];

    return temp;
}
```

More, When I use call function to get the return value, whether I should retain the objective?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     category = [self loadCategory];

     [category retain];

   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Finally, can I replace with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        self.category = [self loadCategory];
       [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.
You could alternatively use...

> [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ..., nil];

This will return an auto-release instance for you.

Also don't forget to call **release** on this array if you **retain** it after you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `category` property is defined as `retain` or `copy`, all three of your examples look correct. Remember to release (or set to `nil`) in `viewDidUnload` or `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're correct, you need to call autorelease in the loadCategory method.  This allows the autorelease pool to handle the release of the array object (it won't be released until your calling code has a change to retain it).  And yes, you need to retain the array from your calling code.  And finally, yes, as long as your self.category property is declared with 'retain':

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *category;
```

And because your property retains the array, you must release it later, e.g. in dealloc.